# Show that if a nonsingular linear system is altered by multiplying its j-th column by c $\not =$ 0, the solution is altered only in the jth component

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I show that if the nonsingular linear system Ax = b is altered by multiplication of its j-th column by c $\not =$ 0, then the solution is altered only in the jth component, which is multiplied by 1/c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working simply because of the definition of matrix product:

Let $A'$ be the modified matrix: column $j$ is multiplied by $c$.
For any vector $x$, let $x'$ be the modified vector: coordinate $j$ is divided by $c$.

Show that $Ax=A'x'$.